# how to force to expand a concatenation of $path/*

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm writing a script to remove some files, but I don't understand how asterisk expansions work. These are my attempts to solve my problem:

```
rm "$path"*.txt
rm "$path"/*.txt
rm "$path"{*}.txt
rm "$path"'*'
rm "/folder/folder\ with\ spaces/*.txt"
```

I also tried replacing double quotes (`"`) with single quotes(`'`) and backticks (`` ` ``). After every script computation, I get an error because the `*` is not substitute. So now I have two questions:

1. Why is the asterisk not expanded?
2. What's the difference between the different quoting character (` " ' ...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In single quoted nothing interesting happns. Not even `$`-variable expansion. Some of those you've tried should work (some depending on the variable content). And, really, `*` is most likely to be not expanded if there're no matches. Are you sure you got your names right?

Comment: yes, in reality i wrong another thing. It works, i get some strange errors because the space-separated-tokens contained in $path, generates other upper (protected) paths of the file system tree.